# Jquery file upload - get number of attachments uploaded

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm currently using the Jquery plugin for file uploads: [Jquery File Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options)

However, nowhere in the documentation does it specify how to get the number of current uploaded files.  It would be nice to query the plugin to check how many have been uploaded. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: by simply using $('#table_fileupload tr').length;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came up with this answer. The problem with the send callback is that it doesn't indicate successful upload. I tried 'done' instead but that doesn't handle the situation where there are deleted uploads.

Instead I count the number of successful templates within the control.
E.g.

```
$("#fileupload .template-download:not('.ui-state-error')").length;
```

I call this on the 'done' callback to refresh the upload count.

Answer (score 5):

`data.files.length`

**[Take a look at the documentation on `send`.](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options)**

You can implement a counter and increment it on `send`.
The number of files uploaded will equal `send - 1`.